# how can i print out json in HTML?

Tags: json, fetch-api

I would like to print out data in my html from the link, but it always says "undefined" and I dont know, where is the problem. Can anyone help, please?

```
let url = 'https://ac7minh6n7s3rw4qfchrofbwai0amiko.lambda-url.eu-north-1.on.aws/';

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(out => console.log('JSON: ', out))
.then(out => document.write('JSON string: ', JSON.stringify(out)))
.catch(err => { throw err })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value passed to the `then` callback is the return value of the previous link in the chain. If that value is a promise, it is resolved before `then` is called.

> ```
> .then(out => console.log('JSON: ', out))
> ```

The return value of `console.log` is `undefined` so you are passing `undefined` into the function which tried to `document.write` the value.

You need to return the value you want to handle:

```
.then(out => {
    console.log('JSON: ', out);
    return out;
})
```

**However** since you aren't creating a new promise, there's really no need to use an extra `then`. You can just merge the two:

```
.then(out => {
    console.log('JSON: ', out);
    document.write('JSON string: ', JSON.stringify(out);
    return out;
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason it is `undefined` is because the return value of `console.log()` is `undefined`. Removing it allows out to be referenced:

```
let url = 'https://ac7minh6n7s3rw4qfchrofbwai0amiko.lambda-url.eu-north-1.on.aws/';

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(out => document.write('JSON string: ', JSON.stringify(out)))
.catch(err => { throw err });
```